# The file InfoPlist.strings couldn't be opened

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can anyone please help me? What should i do to fix the error "The file InfoPlist.strings couldn't be opened because there's no such file"? It's appeared after i've updated my project from SVN. Actually THERE IS InfoPlist.strings in my project, i have no idea why Xcode doesn't see it.

Maybe the following information will help you to understand what's going on: when i expand InfoPlist.strings by clicking on the triangle next to it, then it shows: InfoPlist.strings (English), InfoPlist.strings(German), InfoPlist.strings(French). The English is black, but French and German are red, so i suppose it is probable something wrong with them and it might be the cause of the error. Also, i've got Localizable.strings, which behaves in similar way. It has (when expanded) Localizable.strings (English), Localizable.strings(German), Localizable.strings(French) and just as in InfoPlist.strings English is black whereas French and German are red.

When i look inside my project's folder - there is the following there: a folder named en.lproj contains Localizable.strings and InfoPlist.strings. Folders named fr.lproj and de.lproj contains the same - Localizable.strings and InfoPlist.strings. Seems like i've described everything. Please explain me what to do. I work with Xcode 4.2

Comment: did you try to delete the file and make svn update ?

Comment: do you mean deleting files InfoPlist and Localizable? Not reference but deleting them from the disk? If yes then i tried

Comment: have you found a solution to this ? I'm having the same problem after adding a localization and updating from SVN

Comment: I've just noticed in my project that in the InfoPlist.strings bundle, the default file InfoPlist.strings (English) has a relative path, whereas the one I added, InfoPlist.strings (french) has an absolute path which is grayed out and cannot be changed. The absolute path is the path from the other computer where the project was commited, which is why it's causing the problem on this computer here. Anyone know why it's grayed out ?

Comment: Mutix - i found solution. what i did is i removed reference for InfoPlist.strings and Localizable.strings and then i added these files to the project again and it started working

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I did this also, but when I commit and do an update on my other workstation, I will have to do this again, and again, and again. I will carry on looking for a solution and will let you know if I find one :)

Comment: ok, that would be great. i'll be waiting for you letting me know and if i find a solution before you do i'll write here in these comments

Comment: ok great, I've also posted this question in the Apple Developer Forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3750696?tstart=0

Comment: I have managed to fix this problem, please see my answer below for details :)

Answer (score 10):

I have just managed to fix this problem !

My second Strings.plist file (FR) had an absolute path. The drop down menu for path type (absolute, relative) was greyed out in the info pane of xcode so I could not change it to a relative path.

The solution is to change it manually in the `project.pbxproj` file:

If you open the file to view the source, and search for "plist", find the following line:

```
/* fr */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; name = fr; path = /Users/[YOUR-USER]/[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings; sourceTree = "<absolute>"; };
```

Notice that the `path` attribute is the full path to the file, and that the `sourceTree` attribute is set to `<absolute>`.

Now change the `path` so that it's relative:

```
/Users/[YOUR-USER]/[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
```

should become

```
fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
```

Also change the `sourceTree` value from `<absolute>` to `<group>`

The line should now look like this:

```
/* fr */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; name = fr; path = fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

Repeat these steps for all your localizations that are stuck with absolute paths.

Save the file, commit the changes, and **voilà!** no more *no such file* problem :)

Comment: I'v also fixed this by myself, but vote you up so anyone can see your answer and 'fix' this ugly xcode bug...

Comment: I had this issue while working under Xcode 6.1 and the solution was actually do the inverse: set 'sourceTree' to <absolute> instead of <group>

Answer (score 3):

info.plist source code:
like:
....
{isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; name = en; path = en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings; sourceTree = ""; };
....

check "path" is a absolute path?

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, the code needing change is actually in the `project.pbxproj` file rather than the `info.plist` source

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, easy fix for me: select the plist file in xcode and make sure its "Target Membership" is ON (for the build you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

The path to your Info.plist file is defined in the build settings for the target. Look and see what it's set to. If the project has come from a different machine, it might be an absolute path, but it really should be a path relative to the project root, like `Sources/Info.plist`.

Comment: do you mean i should look at the Packaging in the BuildSettings? If yes then it is MyApp/MyApp - Info.plist. Is it ok or not?

Comment: That depends where the Info.plist file is in the directory structure of your project. Is this the correct path? Go to a terminal and `cd` to the project directory, then type `find . -name '*.plist'`, which will list all the plist files in the project, then we can see where the file should be.

Comment: @JoeRick Info.Plist doesn't have much to do with InfoPlist.strings and the really crappy way Xcode handles them. Depending the changes, Xcode typically keeps moving them around. My thoughts are keep'em all in the <language>.lproj directory, make sure they're in copied resources under build phases, enrolled for the right languages and rock and roll.

Answer (score 0):

Best information is right here. Sorry to be so cheesy as to put a link to this - but they edited it in September - and now it makes sense...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated the files (with empty content) it asked for in the paths it asked for them, since I am new to XCode and it didn't seem to affect my current project I decided that was a acceptable solution/shortcut to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this particular instance of the error was “Info.plist couldn't be opened because there is no such file” was that I had deleted all of the files in the "Project Tests" folder, but was still had "Project Tests" listed under my targets. After deleting the "tests" target, the project built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i pulled my cohort's changes to my local so that i can review and test them. I checked all settings suggested in this thread but they all looked correct-ish. My fix was just to blow away the branch, reset to master and pull the updates to a clean branch. The ol' reboot everything technique.